# Why am I getting a race condition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition, cgal

I'm trying to combine multiple [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) meshes into one single geometry.

I have the following sequential code that works perfectly fine:

```
while (m_toCombine.size() > 1) {
    auto mesh1 = m_toCombine.front();
    m_toCombine.pop_front();
    auto mesh2 = m_toCombine.front();
    m_toCombine.pop_front();

    bool result = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1, mesh2, mesh2);

    m_toCombine.push_back(mesh2);
}
```

Where `m_toCombine` is a `std::list<Triangle_mesh_exact>`.

`Triangle_mesh_exact` is a type of CGAL mesh (triangulated polyhedron geometry). But I don't think it's really relevant to the problem.

Unfortunately, this process is way too slow for my intended application, so I decided to use the "divide to conquer" concept and combine meshes in a parallel fashion:

```
class Combiner
{
public:
    Combiner(const std::list<Triangle_mesh_exact>& toCombine) :
        m_toCombine(toCombine) {};
    ~Combiner() {};

    Triangle_mesh_exact combineMeshes();
    void combineMeshes2();

private:
    std::mutex m_listMutex, m_threadListMutex;
    std::mutex m_eventLock;

    std::list<MiniThread> m_threads;
    std::list<Triangle_mesh_exact> m_toCombine;
    std::condition_variable m_eventSignal;

    std::atomic<bool> m_done = false;

    //void poll(int threadListIndex);
};


Triangle_mesh_exact Combiner::combineMeshes()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueLock(m_eventLock, std::defer_lock);

    int runningCount = 0, finishedCount = 0;

    int toCombineCount = m_toCombine.size();

    bool stillRunning = false;
    bool stillCombining = true;

    while (stillCombining || stillRunning) {
        uniqueLock.lock();

        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_listMutex);
        m_listMutex.lock();
        Triangle_mesh_exact mesh1 = std::move(m_toCombine.front());
        m_toCombine.pop_front();
        toCombineCount--;
        Triangle_mesh_exact mesh2 = std::move(m_toCombine.front());
        m_toCombine.pop_front();
        toCombineCount--;
        m_listMutex.unlock();

        runningCount++;

        auto thread = new std::thread([&, this, mesh1, mesh2]() mutable {
            //m_listMutex.lock();
            CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union(mesh1, mesh2, mesh2);
            
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_listMutex);
            m_toCombine.push_back(mesh2);
            toCombineCount++;
            finishedCount++;
            m_eventSignal.notify_one();
            //m_listMutex.unlock();
        });
        thread->detach();
        
        while (toCombineCount < 2 && runningCount != finishedCount) {
            m_eventSignal.wait(uniqueLock);
        }

        stillRunning = runningCount != finishedCount;
        stillCombining = toCombineCount >= 2;

        uniqueLock.unlock();
    }
    
    return m_toCombine.front();
}
```

Unfortunately, despite being extra careful, I'm getting crashes of memory access violation or errors related to either `mesh1` or `mesh2` destructors.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should use a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` instead of calling `lock`/`unlock` manually on your mutexes.

Comment: I'm worried that `toCombineCount`, `runningCount`, `finishedCount` are not protected by the lock.  What happens, for instance, if `toCombineCount >= 2` at the time the loop condition is checked, but by the time you actually take the lock, it has decreased?

Comment: @molbdnilo: I thought about that, but there should be no other threads running when `m_toCombine.size()` and `m_toCombine.front()` are accessed.

Comment: `-fsanitize=thread` is your friend.

Comment: Hey guys. I edited adding lock_guards and protecting the count variables. Thought they would be atomic and therefore safe to use without locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead complicating things check capability of standard library:

[std::reduce - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)

```cpp
Triangle_mesh_exact combine(Triangle_mesh_exact& a, Triangle_mesh_exact& b)
{
    auto success = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union(a, b, b);
    if (!success) throw my_combine_exception{};
    return b;
}

Triangle_mesh_exact combineAll()
{
    if (m_toCombine.size() == 1) return m_toCombine.front();
    if (m_toCombine.empty()) throw std::invalid_argument("");
    return std::reduce(std::execution::par,
                       m_toCombine.begin() + 1, m_toCombine.end(), 
                       m_toCombine.front(), combine);
}
```

Comment: It severely reduced the number of crashes. But I still get them now and then...

Comment: By the way, had to replace `m_toCombine.begin() + 1` with `std::next(m_toCombine.begin(), 1)` because I'm using a list.

Comment: I do not have your code so can't verify if code compiles. Also I'm not familiar with used library. If you are changing first argument of `std::reduce` (to make single thread) do you still have this crashes? Did you tried run with sanitizer enabled?

Comment: I will investigate further and come back later today.

Comment: I'm using MSVC 2017 which does not support sanitizer. Also, the problem does go away with `std::execution::seq`.

Comment: in 2019 it is available as experimental feature.

Comment: I do not own a license for the 2019. I'm currently using 2017 and so do the rest of the team. It still doesn't make any sense to me. The code seems clean. I can't find where there could possible be a problem of shared resources.

Comment: got it to work by manually managing the memory (allocating each mesh with `new` and destroying with `delete`). Seems like a CGAL bug, indeed.

Comment: Ok this must be caused by fact that `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union` accepts `TriangleMesh` by reference which is not `const`.